# Log4J Ansi Coloring Exceptions

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea

I am using Log4J 2.0 and IntelliJ and I have activated the ANSI coloring option in the log4j2.xml file together with the Grep Console Plugin for IntelliJ when I am debugging in my IDE. This greatly improved reading the logs as I can now distinguish the different log levels by color.

I know it is possible to change the style of the logs of the different log levels, e.g.

```
%highlight{...}{TRACE=red}
```

This works well but now my stacktraces are all printed in white color instead of red. I tried to change the style with the following rule but had no success:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="... %style{%exception}{Bright,Red}"
```

Here is my complete pattern layout:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%-5p %c{1} - %m%n}{TRACE=white} %style{%exception}{Bright,Red}"/>
```

It looks like the exception is printed not through log4j but directy to system out. But still the coloring is affected based on whether `%highlight` is present in the pattern layout.